# JavaFX sorted tableview how to re-sort to default sort order on redisplay

Tags: sorting, javafx, tableview

I have a JavaFX sorted tableview - defined as follows in the overridden initialize method:

```
// Bind the FX tableview to the data - allowing sorting
final SortedList<LoadedWotsitModel> sortedList = 
    new SortedList<LoadedWotsitModel>(configurationDataManager.getLoadedWotsit());

tableLoadedWotsit.setItems(sortedList);
sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(tableLoadedWotsit.comparatorProperty());       

// Sort by time
colTime.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING);
tableLoadedWotsit.getSortOrder().add(colTime);
```

This works fine, other columns in the table are also sortable by the user.

When the dialog is closed and re-opened, it is sorted in the order the user last chose.  I want to be able to make it sort by my default **colTime** column every time the dialog is displayed (not the previously chosen user sort order).

What event can I hook into to re-sort the table when it is displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to use a menu controller and invoke the dialog in code thus:

```
myDialogController.sortByTimeAscending();  
myDialog.show();
```

Allowing me to call a method in the controller directly that performs the sorting.

```
/**
 * Sort by time (ascending).
 */
public void sortByTimeAscending()
{
    colTime.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING);

    tableLoadedWotsit.getSortOrder().clear();  
    tableLoadedWotsit.getSortOrder().add(colTime);
}
```